# uiview animateWithDuration cant hide in same toggle method

Tags: objective-c, uiview, animatewithduration

Trying to hide and show a view from a single method but it seems like it should work to show and hide but its instant.

```c
- (void)toggleMyView:(BOOL)show
{
    CGRect orig = self.originalMyViewFrame; // original frame of the view
    CGRect offScreen = CGRectMake(orig.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height, orig.size.width, orig.size.height);
    if (show) {
        self.myView.frame = offScreen; // set off screen
        self.myView.hidden = NO; // unide the view
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.myView.frame = orig; // animate to original position
        }];
    } else {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            self.myView.frame = offScreen; // animate off screen
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.myView.hidden = YES; // hide when animation finished
        }];
    }
}
```

If I remove the hide logic it animates in nicely.

```c
- (void)toggleMyView:(BOOL)show
{
    CGRect orig = self.originalMyViewFrame; // original frame of the view
    CGRect offScreen = CGRectMake(orig.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height, orig.size.width, orig.size.height);
    if (show) {
        self.myView.frame = offScreen; // set off screen
        self.myView.hidden = NO; // unide the view
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
            self.myView.frame = orig; // animate to original position
        }];
    } else {
        self.myView.hidden = YES; // hide when animation finished
    }
}
```

I dont see why adding the hide logic breaks.

Could this be a memory retain cycle problem?

Comment: For starters you should set the off-screen frame before unhiding the view. (Swap those 2 lines around). This way it will be off screen when it appears rather than flashing in its original location.

Comment: @Dima, thank you for the suggestion.  Since the frame and hidden happen in the same thread it doesnt flash.  But ill change the lines around.